# How to compare two objects in Angular not using reference of object

Tags: angular, typescript

[how typescript comparing two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634154/how-typescript-comparing-two-objects)

```
originaltraits:{
artistic:25,
athletic:24,
goodLooks:70,
happiness:0,
health:81
}
newtraits:{
artistic:25,
athletic:24,
goodLooks:70,
happiness:0,
health:81
}
```

I have these two objects I want to compare these objects' fields not using object reference in Angular then how to compare?

[Why does two equal Objects shows 'not equal" in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785314/why-does-two-equal-objects-shows-not-equal-in-angular-2)

Comment: If you are sure about the order of the properties, you can `JSON.stringify` it and compare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do more comparisons like this one on your project, I highly recommend you using library like deep-equal:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal

It has their types to be used with TypeScript:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/deep-equal

Comment: I get this error if i use deep-equal. error TS2497: Module '"/angularCodeFolder/node_modules/@types/deep-equal/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.     What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 20):

You can compare objects using JSON.stringify(), assuming you have the same order of object properties.
i.e:

```
JSON.stringify(obj1).toLowerCase() === JSON.stringify(obj2).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, object `{Foo=1, Bar =123}` is not equal to object `{Bar =123, Foo=1}`, Some ordering would help.

Comment: besides the ordering problem, this `toLowerCase()` is wrong, will make `{ x: 'FOo' }` equal to `{ x: 'foo' }`